# Convert bitarray to string without using ChrW function

Tags: string, vb.net, unicode

I need to convert bitarray to unicode string (default encoding in vb.net for string type).

For example, let's say the `000000000100000100000000010000100000000001000011` is the bit string representation for 3 x 16bit unicode characters, respectively A = 65; B = 66 and C = 67 (codePoints resulted in conversion of those bits to Integer).

Now, those bits are stored in bitarray. Is there a way to convert the bitarray to string without using the build-in `ChrW` function?

I need this because since I already have the bits ordered as encoding would do, so I try to avoid a double conversion to gain some performance.

Comment: Breaking the string up into 16 character substrings is something you could do with a loop and SubString.  I'm not sure of the best way to convert a binary string to integer. But then using ChrW to get the character for that integer would be the way to go.

Comment: Your bit string is actually big-endian Unicode. Default for VB.NET is little-endian Unicode I think. I think you will be better using `Byte` arrays instead of `BitArray` and `System.Text.Encoding` to convert to/from `String`

Comment: @dviliss - I already said that I dont want to use `ChrW` because is slow

Comment: @SSS - You're correct, little endian is the default, but this is not a problem, I can have the bits ordered in any endianess. I'll give a try to convert to `byte()`, and see how fast it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Byte()` and `System.Text.Encoding`...

```
'BIN: 00000000 01000001 00000000 01000010 00000000 01000011
'HEX:    0   0    4   1    0   0    4   2    0   0    4   3
Dim s1 As String = "ABC"
Console.WriteLine("Original string:" & s1)
Dim b1 As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(s1)
Console.WriteLine("Big-endian UTF-16 (Hex):" & BitConverter.ToString(b1))
b1(1) = b1(1) Or CByte(&H4) 'change byte 1 from 01000001 to 01000101
Dim s2 As String = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(b1)
Console.WriteLine("Modified string:" & s2)
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` will tell you whether your current architecture is big or little endian

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. Now I will make some modifications in my code and than I will test the speed. It should be fast since is only about reading the bits. I hope the conversion to byte() is not too expensive.

Comment: I changed `b1(1) = CByte(b1(1) Or &H4)` to `b1(1) = b1(1) Or CByte(&H4)`. It avoids a type conversion from `Integer` to `Byte`.

Comment: P.S. you can use `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes` to read a file into memory as a byte array

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go, nice knowing the difference that avoid conversion from integer to byte. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this'll actually be faster than using `ChrW()`, and it's probably not the prettiest solution either ;), but I here's how I did it:

To do what you ask I did these steps:

1. Reverse the bit array (since .NET interprets them from left to right, rather than right to left)
2. Create a byte array of the bits. The size of the array should be the amount of bits divided by 8 (8 bits = 1 byte) rounded up to the nearest integer (see [**`Math.Ceiling()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx)).
3. Use [**`Encoding.Unicode`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) to decode the byte array into a string.
4. Convert the string into an array of chars, reverse it, and convert the new char array back into a string.

I've put this together in a function:

```
Public Function BitArrayToString(ByVal Bits As BitArray) As String
    'Reverse the bits (I didn't have access to a compiler tha supports Linq, please don't hate).
    Dim ReversedValues As Boolean() = New Boolean(Bits.Count - 1) {}
    For x As Integer = 0 To Bits.Count - 1
        ReversedValues((ReversedValues.Length - 1) - x) = Bits(x)
    Next

    'Put the reversed bits into a new bit array.
    Dim ReversedBits As New BitArray(ReversedValues)

    'Declare a byte array to 1/8th of the bit array's size, rounded up to the nearest integer.
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = New Byte(Math.Ceiling(ReversedBits.Length / 8) - 1) {}
    ReversedBits.CopyTo(Bytes, 0)

    'Decode the byte array into a string.
    Dim Result As String =  System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Bytes)

    'Get the string as a char array and reverse it.
    Dim Chars As Char() = Result.ToCharArray()
    Array.Reverse(Chars)

    'Return the resulting string from our reversed chars.
    Return New String(Chars)
End Function
```

**Online test:** https://ideone.com/SUTWlJ

Comment: nice work, thank you. But that `Math.Ceiling` only is more expensive than ChrW, which is not really a slow function. It is slower than simply reading the bits, but for sure isn't slower than any `Math` operation.

Comment: @SorinGFS : What do you really need this for? I find it very hard believe that you are actually developing something so time critical that `ChrW()` or `Math.Ceiling()` actually makes a difference. How are you expecting to do this without any kind of operations? Both `Math.Ceiling()` and `ChrW()` are **extremely** fast and execute in _**less**_ than _**0,3 microseconds**_. As seen in this example executing and measuring both at the same time only takes 0,4-0,6 microseconds: https://ideone.com/cgBiKi

Comment: There's really no difference in speed between `Math.Ceiling()` or `ChrW()`. Single math/lookup evaluations usually do not take very long to make, it is the _**looping**_ that's expensive. -- By the way the first measurment you see in my example is just the compilation of those lines, which is always and only done once

Comment: @SorinGFS : Just for fun I made a quick mockup that measures 9998 calls (because the two first are subject to JIT compilation and optimization, and are therefore inaccurate) to my function and calculates the average execution time: https://ideone.com/H7OWeY -- The result was approximately _2,4 microseconds_ per call, meaning you can run it at least _**400 000 times per second**_. If this isn't enough then I think you are overestimating modern hardware. ;)

Comment: I tried your `BitAarrayToString` function, it is nice, works as espected (with one more conversion from double wich is `Math.Ceiling` result to integer because I use `option Strict` ), it is for sure faster than using ChrW, but I need to test both versions using large bitArrays to see the differences. Because of your multiple conversions I tend to beleave that @SSS's way is better, but I will make some tests using 10000 char strings and i will came back with the result.

Comment: @SorinGFS : Ah, so the length is your bottleneck. You use the method that suits your needs and works best, of course! I just wanted you to be aware of that neither `ChrW()` nor `Math.Ceiling()` (or any other simple evaluation method for that matter) is not slow _per se_ and therefore using them does not really have an impact on performance.

Comment: @iVisualVincent - you're right, after a closer look, I realized that the `Math.Ceiling` is used only for determining the size of `byte()` so it doesn't harm, and I can even get rid of it because I already have the length of bitArray as multiple of 16, like this: `Dim Bytes As Byte() = New Byte((ReversedBits.Length \ 8) - 1) {}`. Thanks for your effort.